# Generating function for Newton series?

Tags: functions, series-expansion

The function GeneratingFunction gives generating function for Taylor series. Is there a similar function for [Newton's series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton.27s_series)?

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{x}k \Delta^k [f]\left (0\right)$$

Comment: Your notation seems confused. `k` seems to be use to denote two different things.

Comment: @m_goldberg, I think there is $n$ instead of $k$ in the l.h.s. of the last formula.

Comment: @ybeltukov  last formula is not mine, somebody inserted it. I remove it.

Comment: @m_goldberg Why the downvote?

Comment: I down-voted because of the confused notation. I have removed it.

Comment: T'was me. I edited the question. Sorry, I shouldn't do that half asleep.

Comment: @belisarius Why are you editing with half a sheep? (Maybe I shouldn't ask..)

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what is wanted. A simple example of input and desired output would be very useful.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Because the other half was here http://k38.kn3.net/taringa/0/3/6/7/5/0/nachomsn/E98.jpg?6379

Comment: @belisarius I think I should stick to discussions about [rams](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59347/51).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau For doing symbolic calcs you need symbolic RAMs. That's where most people err http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2013/01/18/article-2264281-16FEE9E3000005DC-300_634x382.jpg