# Workstation specification for Mathematica programming

Tags: parallelization, hardware, gpu

I'm interested in buying a new workstation for my lab and in the process I encountered a lot of options which some I did not fully understand.

The main function this workstation is for numerical simulations which mainly involve: solving large eigenvalue problems and algebraic equations, large lists manipulations and setting (symbolic and numeric) and analyzing large databases.

I am not sure which hardware is needed for each usage (more memory, more CPU speed, more processing cores. etc.), so I can't really tell which system I need.

Furthermore, I am using parallel-computations in my simulations which cuts of a great deal of time for it to run. Thus, I was offered two alternatives: using coprocessors (such as Intel Xeon Phi) or using GPU processing (nVidia Tesla or Titan). 
I would like the advantages and disadvantages of each hardware while using Mathematica for my purposes (including the price issues). 
Moreover, I know that for complicated calculations CUDA programming is necessary for exploiting the most of GPU processing, are there any adjustments I need to make in order to use coprocessors with Mathematica or does it automatically using all available processing-cores?

After my little internet searching I was thinking to get something like the following:

- Intel Xeon 8 core 2.4GHz processors **X2**
- 128Gb RAM memory
- Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor 51XX or 71XX (depending on price) **X2/X3**
- OS SSD drive
- 2Tb data drive **X2**

Is it too much? too little?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: Depends really, can't you run a few examples and see with `MaxMemoryUsed[]` how much you are using? I personally never go beyond 16GB, with what I consider large datasets, but your definition could be different.

Comment: Related or possible duplicates: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69404/buying-a-new-computer-specifically-for-mathematica, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59344/hardware-required-to-perform-large-symbolic-calculations, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28209/hardware-performance-metrics-for-mathematica.

Comment: The choice of the coprocessors depends on your ability to use them from within Mathematica.

Comment: @Karsten7.  What do you mean by "ability to use them from within Mathematica"?

Comment: The way you access nvidia graphic cards (probably CUDALink) is different from how you access a Xeon Phi (OpenMP?) and we don't know if you are an experienced CUDA programmer or much more productive and experienced with the software tools available for Intel Xeon Phi processors.

Comment: @Karsten7. Never used CUDA in my life, the only parallel-computation we did so far was by using the built in parallel functions. My question is if there is anything different I need to do in order to use the Xeon Phi processing cores?

Comment: At the HP "Quick Specs" it says that Mathematica is one the general purpose Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor enabled systems:
http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04168329.pdf?ver=5 .
Do you know to tell me if there is a special to enable it or is it similar to CPU cores?

Comment: I think you really should start from a consideration of what you currently do with Mathematica and determine your need from there; else you will end up spending a ton of money on resources you are hardly ever going to use.

Comment: I don't have a Xeon Phi, but I doubt that that means that the `Parallel*` functions will automatically use the Xeon Phi cores. You should contact Wolfram about how a typical project of yours would make use of either CUDA or Xeon Pi cores.

Comment: @Karsten7. I contacted them, will update once they give an answer.

Comment: Did you get an answer?